# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'Dropout')

Tags: python, keras

I am training my model on LSTM using `keras` library.
Although I have imported the `Dropout` layer, still it gives me the following error:

> File "C:\Users\Faiq
>   Ahmad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line
>   128, in **init**
>       raise TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:', kwarg)
>
> TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'Dropout')

Some people suggested to upgrade keras but no luck.

The code is as follows:

```
keras.models 
import Sequential from sklearn.preprocessing 
import MinMaxScaler from keras.layers 
import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, LSTM , 
model = Sequential() 
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_dim=3, input_shape =(50,), activation= 'relu')) 
model.add(LSTM(32, Dropout=0.2)) 
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax')) 
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.0001), loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=(x_test,y_test), epochs=30 )
```

Comment: The error is from how you are calling the method, please post your code in addition to the error message.

Comment: Which version of keras are you using ? and also please post the code as @BurhanKhalid said

Comment: show the code. Without code we can't help you

Comment: Probably case error — `dropout` should be lower case?

Comment: keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, LSTM , model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_dim=3,  input_shape =(50,), activation= 'relu'))
model.add(LSTM(32, Dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.0001), loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=(x_test,y_test), epochs=30 ) @ven

Comment: It is a typo, use `model.add(LSTM(32, dropout=0.2))`. (see small letter `d` for dropout)

Comment: could you please help with this error now : ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_9_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (304, 50),, i have 50 floating features in a single row, total rows all 380, 304 for training, input shape is 304,50

Comment: I recommend asking a new question for the same.

Answer (score 3):

The usage is incorrect.
Instead of :

```
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_dim=3, input_shape =(50,), activation= 'relu')) 
model.add(LSTM(32, Dropout=0.2))
```

Use:

```
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_dim=3, input_shape =(50,), activation= 'relu')) 
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))
```